# How to filter Exact Online accounts on their classification code?

Tags: rest, get, odata, exact-online

I am trying to make a list of how much accounts have a certain `classification1` code (which currently ranges from 1 to 7).

when accessing the API (which makes use of OData) I get the following error:

> No property 'Code' exists in type 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Guid,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=*********]]' at position 16.

My url looks like this:

```
https://start.exactonline.nl/api/v1/*/crm/Accounts?$inlinecount=allpages&$top=0
```

but when I add a filter it gives the error.

```
https://start.exactonline.nl/api/v1/*/crm/Accounts?$inlinecount=allpages&$top=0&$filter=Classification1/Code eq '1'
```

The API I access is found here:

> https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?id=9
>   https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?id=7

Is there an easier was to receive all the different count values or to fix the filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not possible. `Classification1` is a `Guid`, not an object with the properties of a classification.

If you want to filter on the classification code, you first have to retrieve the `Guid` of the classification, and then filter on the `Guid`.

So first:

```
/api/v1/{division}/crm/AccountClassifications?$filter=Code eq 'yourCode'&$select=ID
```

And then, using the result of the previous call:

```
/api/v1/{division}/crm/Accounts?$filter=Classification1 eq guid'the-guid-you-retrieved'
```